# Get last identity of table and insert to new table

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get the last identity from my table 'usergold' and insert it in a new table table with insert value. I used `select "IDENT_CURRENT('UserGold') As userid"`, new value should be in userid.

But I'm getting an error when I put it in insert, I cannot create the trigger. Please check my code.

```
create trigger addrole
on UserGold
after Insert
as 
Begin

select  IDENT_CURRENT('UserGold') As userid
insert into AspNetUserRoles values(userid,'2c258e8d-c648-4b38-9b01-989d4dd525fe')
end
```

i tried

```
create trigger addrole
on UserGold
after Insert
as 
Begin
declare
@userid nvarchar(50)
select @userid=userId from UserGold where userId=IDENT_CURRENT('UserGold')
insert into AspNetUserRoles(UserId,RoleId) values(@userid,'2c258e8d-c648-4b38-9b01-989d4dd525fe')
end
```

igot this error **"Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric** " from
***select @userid=userId from UserGold where userId=IDENT_CURRENT('UserGold')***

Comment: You need to use `INSERTED` pseudo to get all the rows

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Don't use `IDENT_CURRENT` - use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead

Comment: my primary key type nvarchar(50),IDENT_CURRENT and SCOPE_IDENTITY() not working

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` statement is not written correctly.

Try

```
INSERT INTO AspNetUserRoles ( [col_1_name], [col_2_name] )
VALUES (
    ( SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ( 'UserGold' ) ),
    '2c258e8d-c648-4b38-9b01-989d4dd525fe'
);
```

**Note:** Replace the column holder names ( col_1_name, col_2_name ) with the actual column names being inserted to.

Comment: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId', table 'Resto.dbo.AspNetUserRoles'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated. tihs Ident_current returning null

Comment: Does UserGold actually have an current identity value set? Run DBCC CHECKIDENT ( 'UserGold' ); in SSMS to check the table's current identity value, otherwise, you can use ISNULL ( IDENT_CURRENT ( 'UserGold' ), 0 ) to ensure at least a value is entered, however, be aware that it will always insert 0 (in my example) when no current identity value is available.